# String cannot be parsed to HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a weird problem with my PHP and Javascript files.  I have HTML content in my Database, and I want to insert that into my page.  So, I get the values and pass it to the HTML page like this:

```
$string = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", htmlentities($formcontent) );
```

I get a string which I can use to pass it to my javascript, like this:

```
var contentform = '<?php echo $string; ?>';
```

Now I want to insert this HTML into my page.  I've got a div set up, but if I insert it, it keeps getting treated as a string so there isn't any DOM to display.

```
var htmltrimmed = $.trim(contentform);

var htmlcontent = $.parseHTML(htmltrimmed);
console.log(htmltrimmed);
$('#currentform').html(htmltrimmed);
```

But when I check the console of check the actual div, there is just a plain string inserted.:

[image: string in html]

You see it gets treated as a string. But I really don't understand why it's acting like this.

EDIT:

This is the contentform value, I've cut some of it off, because the string is very long, but the actual value is a valid HTML string!:

```
&lt;form class=&quot;form-horizontal&quot; &gt;&lt;fieldset&gt;&lt;!-- Form Name --&gt;&lt;legend&gt;DMN SGT&lt;/legend&gt;&lt;!-- Multiple Radios --&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;control-group&quot;&gt;  &lt;label class=&quot;control-label&quot; for=&quot;multipleradios-0&quot;&gt;Grund der Messebesuch&lt;/label&gt;  &lt;div class=&quot;controls&quot;&gt;    &lt;label class=&quot;radio&quot; for=&quot;multipleradios-0-0&quot;&gt;      &lt;input type=&quot;radio&quot; name=&quot;multipleradios-0&quot; id=&quot;multipleradios-0-0&quot; value=&quot;Konkretes Interesse an Produkt&quot; checked=&quot;checked&quot;&gt;
```

Comment: What is the value that you're assigning to `contentform`?

Comment: See EDIT, it's a very long string so I've cut some off it, idea should be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use  [**$.parseHTML**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) for your example

see this Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/Lny2m0kc/1/

```
var t = $.parseHTML('&lt;form class=&quot;form-horizontal&quot; &gt;&lt;fieldset&gt;&lt;!-- Form Name --&gt;&lt;legend&gt;DMN SGT&lt;/legend&gt;&lt;!-- Multiple Radios --&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;control-group&quot;&gt;  &lt;label class=&quot;control-label&quot; for=&quot;multipleradios-0&quot;&gt;Grund der Messebesuch&lt;/label&gt;  &lt;div class=&quot;controls&quot;&gt;    &lt;label class=&quot;radio&quot; for=&quot;multipleradios-0-0&quot;&gt;      &lt;input type=&quot;radio&quot; name=&quot;multipleradios-0&quot; id=&quot;multipleradios-0-0&quot; value=&quot;Konkretes Interesse an Produkt&quot; checked=&quot;checked&quot;&gt;')
console.log(t);

$('#test').html(t[0].data)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer. I just had to get it from the array, like you did with this line: t[0].data

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the HTML in the string you echo from PHP is encoded. There is no native JS function to decode HTML so you would need to provide your own, something like this:

```
function htmlDecode(value){
    return String(value)
        .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
        .replace(/&#39;/g, "'")
        .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
        .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
        .replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
}

$('#currentform').html(htmlDecode(contentform));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1rpn6e1k/)

Answer (score 1):

Please try with html_entity_decode in stead of htmlentities

```
$string = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", html_entity_decode($formcontent) );
```